# Office 2010 won't uninstall OR install

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-office-2010

So I had to suddenly end the install process of office 2010. I clicked "Cancel" and let it undo or whatever for about 20 minutes, and when the bar didn't move whatsoever, I just ended the process in task manager.

I restarted my computer, put the disc back in and ran it. Whenever I uninstall, I get this message:

[image]

If I'm installing:

[image]

I have restarted my computer many times, it's not that.

Also, someone in the comments told me to paste the log file here, however I can't find it in any of the places I think they would be... Program files, etc... If someone would tell me where they are I'll post a link to them.

They said to check in my user file, however I just did and didn't see anything ([This is my user file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgMCe.png))

If I open a word document (.docx), this comes up for MAYBE 1/10th of a second, then goes away:

[image]

Comment: inside the temp folder you should have Log files from the setup. Zip and upload them.

Comment: What temp folder?

Comment: the one under the user account folder.

Comment: This is my user account folder: http://i.imgur.com/aCRAaKN.png

Comment: the temp folder is under AppData\local

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think @magicandre1981 refers to temporary folder of your User, open the run box ([image] + <kbd>R</kbd>) and type `%temp%`. Done that, delete the temporary files and try again to uninstall.

If you still can not uninstall, you can use the steps in [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971179) from Microsoft.